# 960gs breaks in Compatibility mode in IE 8 and earlier

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility, 960.gs

Ok, here is my dilemma. The 960 gs I am using breaks when you view it in compatibility mode in IE8 and earlier. My company will not allow code that removes/hides compatibility mode. They are going to update to a newer version of IE but not for awhile and this site has to be working by the end of the month. So I am really stuck and need some help. Here is the test code I am using below. I also supplied it in JS fiddle so you can see all of the code. Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gtt9c7u/embedded/result/

```
<div class="container_14">
<div class="grid_6 alpha">
<div class="grid_6 alpha omega results">
  <div id="bulletin" class="tooltip" title="Tip1">
    <h5><b>Bulletin Board</b></h5>
    <p></p>
  </div> <!-- end inner Bulletin div (any margins or padding for this article add to this div --> 
</div> <!-- end Bulletin Board --> 
<div class="clear"></div> <!-- Creates new row in grid system -->       

<div class="grid_3 alpha results1 cursor">
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; dispaly: block; cursor: pointer; border-bottom:0;" title="Getting started">
  <div id="started" class="tooltip" title="Tip4">
    <h3>Getting Started</h3>
  </div> <!-- end inner Getting Started div (any margins or padding for this article add to this div --> 
  </a>
</div> <!-- end Getting Started -->  

<div class="grid_3 omega results1 cursor">
  <div id="ownCareer" class="tooltip" title="Tip5">
    <h3>Own Your Career</h3>
    </div> <!-- end inner Own Your Career div (any margins or padding for this article add to this div --> 
</div> <!-- end Own Your Career --> 
<div class="clear"></div> <!-- Creates new row in grid system -->       

<div class="grid_3 alpha results1 cursor">
  <div id="ace" class="tooltip" title="Tip6">
    <h3>Ace Your Job</h3>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end Ace Your Job -->  

<div class="grid_3 omega results1 cursor">
  <div id="develop" class="tooltip" title="Tip7">
    <h3>Develop Your Team</h3>
  </div> <!-- end inner Develop Your Team div (any margins or padding for this article add to this div --> 
</div> <!-- end Develop Your Team -->    
</div> <!-- End grid 6 Div -->

<div class="grid_8 omega">
<div class="grid_6 alpha results">
  <div id="whatIs" class="tooltip" title="Tip2">
    <h4>What is the Learning and Development Network?</h4>
  </div> <!-- end inner WhatIs div (any margins or padding for this article add to this div --> 
</div> <!-- end What is -->

<div class="grid_2 omega results">
  <div id="quickLearning" class="tooltip" title="Tip3">
    <h3>Quick Learning Break</h3>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="Take 5 Icon" />
    <a href="#quickLearningBox" title="Quick Learning Break" class="lightbox"></a>
      <div id="quickLearningBox">
        <h3>Quick Learning Break</h3>
        <p>More content...</p>
        <a href="#">Quick Learning Break</a>
      </div> <!-- Easybox div - all contents in this div will appear in the lightbox for this div --> 
  </div> <!-- end inner Quick Learning div (any margins or padding for this article add to this div --> 
</div> <!-- end Quick Learning -->
<div class="clear"></div> <!-- Creates new row in grid system -->       

<div class="grid_8 alpha omega">
<div class="grid_6 alpha results1">
  <div id="featured">
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Featured Programs for Front Line Leaders</h3><br/>            
      </div> <!--End Div item-->

      <div class="item">
        <h3>Featured Programs for Trainers</h3><br/>              
      </div> <!--End Grid 6-->

      <div class="item">
        <h3>Featured Programs for All Associates</h3><br/>
      </div> <!--End Div item-->

    </div>  <!--End Owl Demo-->
  </div> <!--End Div Featured-->
</div> <!-- end Featured courses -->

<div class="grid_2 omega results1 cursor mydiv">
  <div id="keyLearning" class="tooltip" title="Tip9">
      <h3>Key Learning Resources</h3>
      <img src="images/graduate23_100px.png" alt="My Learning" />
      <a href="#keyLearningBox" title="Key Learning Resources" class="lightbox"></a>
        <div id="keyLearningBox">
          <h3>Key Learning Resources</h3>
          <p>More content...</p>
          <a href="#">Key Learning Resources</a>
        </div> <!-- Easybox div - all contents in this div will appear in the lightbox for this div --> 
   </div> <!-- end inner Key Learning Resources div (any margins or padding for this article add to   this div --> 
  </div> <!-- end Key Learning Resources -->   

  <div class="grid_2 omega results1">
  <div id="about" class="tooltip" title="Tip10">
      <h3>Learn About, Inc's Culture</h3>
      <a href="#aboutBox" title="Learn About" class="lightbox"></a>
        <div id="aboutBox">
          <h3>Learn About, Inc's Culture</h3>
          <p>More content...</p>
          <a href="#">Learn About</a>
        </div> <!-- Easybox div - all contents in this div will appear in the lightbox for this div --> 
      <img src="http://placehold.it/85x15" alt="Core Values" />
  </div> <!-- end inner myLearning div (any margins or padding for this article add to this div --> 
</div> <!-- end Learn About -->

</div><!-- end inner grid 8 alpha container -->
</div><!-- end outer grid_8 omega -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Comment: Compatibility mode is for old sites that are broken in modern browsers. It shouldn't be turned on for sites which work with it turned off. Trying to cater for it explicitly is a fool's errand.

Comment: I agree but is what the company is requesting. I have no say in it. We've pushed back but they are adamant since it is a company wide rollout that it works in compatibility mode.

Comment: It would seem that even JSFiddle doesn't work in IE8 ;D

Comment: Look for another job. Microsoft doesn't support or update Windows XP or IE8 anymore. That alone is a security risk.

Comment: Making your website compatible with older versions of IE make sense, but outright refusing you to allow you to set a `<meta>` tag to tell IE to use standards mode seems an odd decision.

Comment: Good luck then, IE8 in compatibility mode is a big mess.